# How do I parse a curly bracket structured file (e.g. Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, parsing, data-structures, swift-mt

The contents of the file looks like (any deep possible):

```
{
  {bla: XBS/333: bla9,1-}
}
{
  {q: XBS/333: bla9,1-}
  {{}}
  {x:{t: QWA/333: C}}
}
```

How do I parse it to e.g. an Array or a Hash with Ruby? What do you think is a good data structure object to store it to?

(It's a SWIFT-Banking file, if that helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any proper parsers generator, for example http://treetop.rubyforge.org/